# Number splitting

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers

So, my question is how to split the number into vector of its parts?

Example: n = 1000 => vector(1,0,0,0)

I came to this option:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
std::vector<int> split(int number)
{
    int n = number;
    int length = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        length++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        int degree1 = pow(10, length - i);
        int degree2 = pow(10, length - i - 1);
        vec.push_back(number % degree1 / degree2);
    }
    return vec;
}
```

However, I think there is a more appropriate way to do it

Comment: An even simpler way is to "print" the number into a `std::string` (e.g. with `std::ostringstream`) and copy the characters one by one into your `std::vector`. Another way is to use `operator %` (modulo, remainder). With `% 10` you get the last digit. So, you can separate the digits from right to left. Either insert digits at beginning of vector or (better) push them back and reverse the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An even simpler way is to "print" the number into a `std::string` (e.g. with `std::ostringstream` or `std::to_string()`) and copy the characters one by one into your `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> split(int number)
{
  std::vector<int> vec;
  if (number < 0) return vec;
  std::string text = std::to_string(number);
  for (char c : text) vec.push_back(c - '0');
  return vec;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
  for (int i : vec) out << ' ' << i;
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "split(1000):" << split(1000) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
split(1000): 1 0 0 0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/966fd0211cc91bac)

Another way is to use `operator %` (modulo, remainder). With `% 10` you get the last digit. So, you can separate the digits from right to left. Either insert digits at beginning of vector or (better) push them back and `std::reverse` the final result.

Sample:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> split(int number)
{
  std::vector<int> vec;
  if (number >= 0) {
    do {
      vec.push_back(number % 10);
      number /= 10;
    } while (number);
    std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  }
  return vec;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
  for (int i : vec) out << ' ' << i;
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "split(1000):" << split(1000) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
split(1000): 1 0 0 0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be856897ecff6ff3)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to push the digits into the vector in reverse order (using the `n % 10` and `n /= 10` operations), then call [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) on the vector when done:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> split(int number)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    while (number > 0) {
        vec.push_back(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    return vec;
}
```